# react-draft-wysiwyg - render saved content to update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, draftjs

I'm using [react-draft-wysiwyg](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/) in a project and I'm having a 'big' problem.

After hours of trying, I can't make an render my database's content.

First, I tried and succeed saving in MongoDB an "overview" (contentState) with the following code:

```
 <Editor initialContentState={person.overview}
         toolbarClassName="rdw-storybook-toolbar"
         wrapperClassName="rdw-storybook-wrapper"
         editorClassName="editor" onContentStateChange={this.onContentStateChange}
         toolbar={{ options: [
                         'inline',
                         'blockType',
                         'fontSize',
                         'fontFamily',
                         'list',
                         'textAlign',
                         'colorPicker',
                         'link',
                         'embedded',
                         'emoji',
                         'remove',
                         'history'], 
                        }}
```

**My Component constructor:**

this.state = { person: { isEdit: false, } };

As you can see, I don't set in the constructor person: { overview: {} }, because if I do it I get the following error:

> invalid RawDraftContentState ▶ 24 stack frames were collapsed.
> ./src/index.js src/index.js:19 16 | ); 17 | 18 | 19 | ReactDOM.render(
> 20 |  21 |  22 | ,

So I just don't set overview: {} in the constructor and **the saving process is working correctly.**

After that, I'm trying to render the saved content in an component to be able to make changes and update. It would be great if I can use the same component to edit and save to make it reusable, but it's not a must.

The thing is that although I set this.setState({person: overview: contentFromDatabase}) (checked, it's being seted), the component shows blank, nothing. You can write from zero but it's not loading the content.

I have to say that right now after hours and hours I'm a bit confused with the editorState and contentState stuff, but I think that my DB's content is a RawDraftContent, right?

Here is my DB's document:

```js
    "_id": ObjectId("5b3d2897589a5e2fa4ba60ea"),
    "overview": {
      "blocks": [
        {
          "key": "ekrl0",
          "text": "this is the CONTENT",
          "type": "unstyled",
          "depth": 0,
          "inlineStyleRanges": [
            {
              "offset": 14,
              "length": 2,
              "style": "BOLD"
            }
          ],
          "entityRanges": []
        }
      ]
    },
    "createdAt": ISODate("2018-07-04T20:05:43.129Z"),
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of saving content in DB as editor state you can do something like this:

```
import {
  Editor,
  EditorState,
  ContentState,
  convertFromHTML,
  CompositeDecorator,
  convertToRaw,
  getDefaultKeyBinding,
} from 'draft-js';

const blocks = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()).blocks;
    const value = blocks.map(block => (!block.text.trim() && '\n') || block.text).join('\n');
```

and for retrieving the data you can do:

```
componentWillMount() { 
      const { value } = this.props
      const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(value));
      const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
        blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
      );
      this.state = {
        editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
          state,
          compositeDecorator,
        ),
      };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was using contentState instead of editorState, but I tried replacing it and writting your code. I put the first part with "const blocks.." in my save() method, before calling the action to save. The second part in componentWillReceiveProps method, after actually fetching the database's data (So I put this.setState instead of this.state = ...). Also I wrote "CompositeDecorator" instead of "compositeDecorator" because I think that it was what you wanted to type.  The saving is working great!

Comment: But when I'm trying to edit the component I'm getting the following error:  `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): decorator.getDecorations is not a function`

Comment: I change my last <Editor> for <Editor initialEditorState={person.internship} onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}/> to use editorState instead of contentState.

Comment: If I remove the Composite Decorator (just `EditorState.createWithContent(state)`), **it renders the database content correctly, but it's not applying any style (no bold, no italic, etc, it's just plain text)**

Comment: @DaríoGL CompositeDecorators are for styling text, you need to put composite decorators in order to apply any style to the specific text inside your editor.

Comment: CompisiteDecorator will look something like this:
const compositeDecorator = new CompositeDecorator([
      {
        strategy: this.handleStrategy,
        component: HandleSpan,
      },
    ]);
where this.handleStrategy will define the element you like to apply styling.
And HandleSpan is the component should be replaced with defined Strategy.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DaríoGL Please accept the answer if that solved your issue.

Comment: Well, I used part of your code to solve it. The difference is that I converted to raw and then from raw instead of using convertfromhtml. But your answer helped me to solve it, so I accepted it.

Comment: @DaríoGL How did you end up converting the database content into actual text?